# phpmyadmin export naming templates / variables

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, export

While exporting `SQL` from `phpmyadmin` these is an option to give the exported file some variables to be included in the name of the file itself ( and also save it like some sort of "template" under `settings-->export`)  , for example :

`__DB__` or 
`@DATABASE@`

`@HTTPHOST@`

`@TABLE@` ( if exporting from a table )

`@SERVER@` ( for IP )

`@USER@` or `__USER__` (not always...)

etc..

I also know of some time variables like

`%F` and the standard `%Y`,`%M`,`%D`, `%m` ,`%s` etc ( `strftime` ) ..

so for example `@DATABASE@-@SERVER@-%F` will give me a file name like :

`dbname-127.0.0.1-2019-03-21.sql`

I have searched for documentation on these, but could not find on the [official phpmyadmin docs](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/import_export.html?highlight=export#export) . I also noticed that they do not react the same on all servers .

***My question is:***

Are there any other variables - What is ( or where to find ) the complete list of documented variables and the correct usage format ( `__x__` or `@NAME@` ) ?

How ( or where ) are they set on a server / user basis - and can one set / enable / disable these on own server - or even add new ones ?

Comment: [This](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#faq6-27) seems to list all of the variables that are available and specifically mentions the use of [strftime format strings](https://secure.php.net/strftime) for dates and times.

Comment: According to the comments in Util.php the `__DB__` format is deprecated and has been replaced. `/* Replacement mapping */
        /*
         * The __VAR__ ones are for backward compatibility, because user
         * might still have it in cookies.
         */`

Comment: The list is `'@HTTP_HOST@' => $vars['http_host'],
            '@SERVER@' => $vars['server_name'],
            '__SERVER__' => $vars['server_name'],
            '@VERBOSE@' => $vars['server_verbose'],
            '@VSERVER@' => $vars['server_verbose_or_name'],
            '@DATABASE@' => $vars['database'],
            '__DB__' => $vars['database'],
            '@TABLE@' => $vars['table'],
            '__TABLE__' => $vars['table'],
            '@PHPMYADMIN@' => $vars['phpmyadmin_version'],`

Comment: I see nothing that would allow them to be set per user or host. Just in templates.

Comment: @Dave so every user need to set them as default in `settings -> Export` ? :-) and maybe just write an answer for me to accept ?

Comment: I believe so and they get stored in the `pma__userconfig` table in the `phpmyadmin` database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__xx__` variables exist for backward compatibility when things like that were stored in cookies. From the code:

```
    /* Replacement mapping */
    /*
     * The __VAR__ ones are for backward compatibility, because user
     * might still have it in cookies.
     */
   $replace = array(
       '@HTTP_HOST@' => $vars['http_host'],
       '@SERVER@' => $vars['server_name'],
       '__SERVER__' => $vars['server_name'],
       '@VERBOSE@' => $vars['server_verbose'],
       '@VSERVER@' => $vars['server_verbose_or_name'],
       '@DATABASE@' => $vars['database'],
       '__DB__' => $vars['database'],
       '@TABLE@' => $vars['table'],
       '__TABLE__' => $vars['table'],
       '@PHPMYADMIN@' => $vars['phpmyadmin_version'])
```

Since there is no way to have a default set of `export` values for all users you could create a set for your users and store them in the `pma__userconfig` table in the `phpmyadmin` database. The values are stored in `JSON` format.

Comment: Thanks, BTW you can create a defaults also under `settings` --> `export` for the whole server but not on a user basis... thanks again !